# get substring using regex in java

Tags: java

Could you please help me to split to get substring using regex

for example :

```
05-05-2018 - Ab12aB 0-1 Bq12B (Acb123)
```

or

```
05-05-2018 - Ab12aB 0-1 Bq12B
```

Result:

```
05-05-2018
Ab12aB
0-1
Bq12B
Acb123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to find the strings start with a letter or number, and contains only `-` or letter or number:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w[-\\w]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("05-05-2018 - Ab12aB 0-1 Bq12B (Acb123)");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Result:

```
05-05-2018
Ab12aB
0-1
Bq12B
Acb123
```